# SMTP: Error 554, message is not RFC compliant

Tags: smtp

Our custom automatic email delivery service is hitting this problem with a couple of our clients' SMTP servers. It only happens with about three of them--the message is bounced back with the following response from the SMTP server:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
host clients.host.name [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 554 Message is not RFC compliant
```

Here's the email header generated by our custom application. Note that our own emails go through without any problems, but our application's don't.

```
Return-path: <ouremail@our.domain>
Received: from [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] (helo=our.stmp.server)
by clients.smtp.server with smtp (Exim 4.69)
(envelope-from <ouremail@our.domain>)
id 1LQNiv-0008MM-IM
for clientsaddress@clients.domain; Fri, 23 Jan 2009 13:13:33 -0200
Subject: Test Mail
From: <ouremail@our.domain>
To: <clientsaddress@clients.domain>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
X-Mailer: ourCompany (ourcompanys.web.site)
Importance: Normal
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="OURCOMPANYSsoftsmtp123X4560102897C"
X-Scan-Signature: e932e7231c8991cb29810b36327eaa17


--OURCOMPANYSsoftstmp123X4560102897C
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

BASE64ENCODING

--OURCOMPANYSsoftstmp123X4560102897C--
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `Message-ID` or `Date` headers in the messages being generated by your program.  That may be why they're getting rejected.

Also, strictly speaking SMTP requires that the lines are CRLF delimited.  I can't tell whether that's what you've got or not.

Comment: Just to clarify: some mail servers will add Message-ID and/or Date headers if they're missing, but they should only do that on locally generated content, not content that's accepted from a different domain.

Comment: sometimes the trick is spotting what's _not_ there :)  To clarify, it's quite common for an MUA not to add those headers, so they're added by the first MTA.  But that should never happen on MTA -> MTA connections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a Date:  header either.

Comment: Alnitak mentioned that an hour before your post.

Comment: AH, yes, somehow read right over that.